# Unable to populate Spinner with Dynamic JSON data

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I am working on a screen having a spinner.I want to populate the spinner with the json data containing proficiency id and name that is received from server .I am storing the data received in Bean_ProficiencyLevel.It contains id and name.I am using a customized array adapter named Adapter_Proficiency which load the text view with name only.I am using this adapter to populate the spinner.I am getting unexpected results here.Spinner is displaying values as shown below:

**1. ScreenShot**

[image: Sceenshot]

After clicking any item i am getting the expected value.e.g. Excellent in the figure below:

**2. ScreenShot**

[image: SceenShot]

I am not able to find out why in the listing of spinner i am getting inappropriate data before selection.My code is given below:

**Adapter_Proficiency.java**

```
public class Adapter_Proficiency extends ArrayAdapter<Bean_ProficiencyLevel> {
private ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel> items;
private ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel> itemsAll;
private ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel> suggestions;
private int viewResourceId;

public Adapter_Proficiency(Context context, int viewResourceId, ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel> items) {
    super(context, viewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
    this.itemsAll = (ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel>) items.clone();
    this.suggestions = new ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel>();
    this.viewResourceId = viewResourceId;
}

public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(viewResourceId,parent,false);
    }
    Bean_ProficiencyLevel bean_proficiencyLevel = items.get(position);
    if (bean_proficiencyLevel != null) {
        TextView txtProficiency = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtProficiency);
        if (txtProficiency != null) {
            txtProficiency.setText(bean_proficiencyLevel.getProficiencyValue());
        }
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return nameFilter;
}

Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        String str = ((Bean_ProficiencyLevel) (resultValue)).getProficiencyValue();
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            suggestions.clear();
            for (Bean_ProficiencyLevel bean_proficiencyLevel : itemsAll) {
                if (bean_proficiencyLevel.getProficiencyValue().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    suggestions.add(bean_proficiencyLevel);
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel> filteredList = (ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel>) results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (Bean_ProficiencyLevel c : filteredList) {
                add(c);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
}
```

**Tab_TechnicalSkills.java**

```
public class Tab_TechincalSkills extends Activity {

private ListView lv_technicalSkills;
String URL_GetAllSkillDetails, URL_GetAllProficiencyLevel;
private APIConfiguration apiConfiguration;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private ArrayList<Bean_Skill> arrayList;
private ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel> arrayListProficiency;
private Adapter_Skill adapter_skill;
AutoCompleteTextView actv_skill, actv_proficiency;
HttpRequestProcessor httpRequestProcessor;
Bean_Skill bean_skill;
Spinner sp_proficiency;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_technical_skill);
    //findViewByID
    actv_skill = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_skillName);
    //actv_proficiency = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_proficiency);
    sp_proficiency = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_proficiency);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<Bean_Skill>();
    arrayListProficiency = new ArrayList<Bean_ProficiencyLevel>();
    httpRequestProcessor = new HttpRequestProcessor();
    lv_technicalSkills = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_Technical_Skills);
    prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Prefs_Registration.pacakgename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Get userID
    String userID = prefs.getString(Prefs_Registration.get_user_id, "");
    //Get Access token
    String accessToken = prefs.getString(Prefs_Registration.get_AccessToken, "");
    //Get Api_end_point
    apiConfiguration = new APIConfiguration();
    String api = apiConfiguration.getApi();
    URL_GetAllSkillDetails = api + "/webservice/getAllSkills?user_id=" + userID + "&access_token=" + accessToken;
    URL_GetAllProficiencyLevel = api + "/webservice/getProficiencyLevels?user_id=" + userID + "&access_token=" + accessToken;
    //Get listing of skills
    new SkillDetailsTask().execute();
    //Get all proficiency levels
    new ProficiencyLevelDetailsTask().execute();
}

//Get list of all skills
class SkillDetailsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String response = httpRequestProcessor.gETRequestProcessor(URL_GetAllSkillDetails);
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.e("JSONARRAY", s);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                String text = jsonObject.getString("text");

                // Adding data to Bean
                bean_skill = new Bean_Skill();
                bean_skill.setSkill_id(id);
                bean_skill.setSkill_name(text);

                //Adding bean object to array
                arrayList.add(bean_skill);
            }
            Adapter_Skill adapter_skill = new Adapter_Skill(Tab_TechincalSkills.this, R.layout.single_row_skill, arrayList);
            actv_skill.setAdapter(adapter_skill);
            actv_skill.setThreshold(2);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class ProficiencyLevelDetailsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String response = httpRequestProcessor.gETRequestProcessor(URL_GetAllProficiencyLevel);
        Log.e("ResponseProficiency", response);
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);


            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                Log.e("idProficiency", id);
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                Bean_ProficiencyLevel bean = new Bean_ProficiencyLevel();

                //Adding data to Bean
                bean.setId(id);
                bean.setProficiencyValue(name);

                //Adding bean to ArrayList
                arrayListProficiency.add(bean);
            }
            Adapter_Proficiency adapter_proficiency = new Adapter_Proficiency(Tab_TechincalSkills.this, R.layout.single_row_proficiency, arrayListProficiency);
            sp_proficiency.setAdapter(adapter_proficiency);
            /*actv_proficiency.setAdapter(adapter_proficiency);
            actv_proficiency.setThreshold(0);*/
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


}
```

**Bean_ProficiencyLevel.java**

```
public class Bean_ProficiencyLevel {
String id, proficiencyValue;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProficiencyValue() {
    return proficiencyValue;
}

public void setProficiencyValue(String proficiencyValue) {
    this.proficiencyValue = proficiencyValue;
}
```

}

**HttpRequestProcessor.java**

```
public class HttpRequestProcessor {
String jsonString, requestMethod, requestURL, jsonResponseString, responseCode;
StringBuilder sb;
Response response; // Response class will store http JSON Response string and Response Code

// This method will process POST request and  return a response object containing Response String and Response Code
public Response pOSTRequestProcessor(String jsonString, String requestURL) {
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    response = new Response();
    try {
        // Sending data to API
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonString); // Transmit data by writing to the stream returned by getOutputStream()
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        // Read the response
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String responseData = br.readLine();
        while (responseData != null) {
            sb.append(responseData);
            responseData = br.readLine();
        }
        // Reading the response code
        int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
      //  Log.e("Response Code", String.valueOf(responseCode));
        response.setResponseCode(responseCode);
        br.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jsonResponseString = sb.toString();
    response.setJsonResponseString(jsonResponseString);
    return response; //return response object
}

// This method will process http GET request and return json response string
public String gETRequestProcessor(String requestURL) {
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
        int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.e("Status", String.valueOf(status));
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String responseData = br.readLine();
        while (responseData != null) {
            sb.append(responseData);
            responseData = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jsonResponseString = sb.toString();
    return jsonResponseString;
}

public String pUTRequestProcessor(String jsonString, String requestURL) {
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        //sending data to API
        URL urlMobileUser = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlMobileUser.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000); //Sets the maximum time to wait for an input stream read to complete before giving up
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000); //Sets the maximum time in milliseconds to wait while connecting
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonString);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        //getting response from API
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String responseData = br.readLine();
        while (responseData != null) {
            sb.append(responseData);
            responseData = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Connection error", ex.toString());
    }
    jsonResponseString = sb.toString();
   // Log.e("JSON Response String", jsonResponseString);
    return jsonResponseString;
}
```

}

Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ArrayAdapter` Adapter_Proficiency would be perfect for a `ListView`, but for `spinners` you need another method. In order for the spinner to display the right values you need to override another method, the getDropDownView method and do exactly what you do in getView method, like this:

```
@Override    
public View getDropDownView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(viewResourceId,parent,false);
    }
    Bean_ProficiencyLevel bean_proficiencyLevel = items.get(position);
    if (bean_proficiencyLevel != null) {
        TextView txtProficiency = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtProficiency);
        if (txtProficiency != null) {
            txtProficiency.setText(bean_proficiencyLevel.getProficiencyValue());
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: user3597165 , It means ,i have to use both getView() and getDropDownView() method .When i used only getDropDownView() method, drop down is displaying is correct values but hexadecimal value is set on the view after selection.When i used both getView() and getDropDownView() method ,its working good but taking some time for selection.Thanks for your help user3597165.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going into the specific details but in the line at the adapter

```
txtProficiency.setText(bean_proficiencyLevel.getProficiencyValue());
```

You are setting the object name to the textView
check 
`getProficiencyValue()` function,I am positive that you are returning an object of `Bean_ProficiencyLevel` by calling a `toString()` on it,Change it and make it return a correct string value
Also may i suggest you use Gson library to deserialize data and RetroFit for network calls? The methods you using are pretty obsolete in android programming standards now

Comment: bean_proficiencyLevel.getProficiencyValue() is giving me String data.So  txtProficiency.setText(bean_proficiencyLevel.getProficiencyValue()); is setting the string value.I checked it.

Comment: Bean class and the getter methods

Comment: public class Bean_ProficiencyLevel {
    String id, proficiencyValue;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProficiencyValue() {
        return proficiencyValue;
    }

    public void setProficiencyValue(String proficiencyValue) {
        this.proficiencyValue = proficiencyValue;
    }
}

Comment: I'm answering this from mobile could you update your question with above code

Comment: insomniac ,please check now